# Java read specific file store in arraylist

Tags: java, parsing, io

Suppose I would like to read input text file into lists.

File contents:

```
/* ignore comments */
/*TaskID <space> Duration <space> Dependency <comma> <Dependency>...*/

A 1 
B 2 A(-1)
C 3 B,A
D 4 D
```

How do I avoid reading the comments and store each line in a proper order?

Ex:

```
task = {A,B,C,D}

duration = {1,2,3,4}

dependency = {, A(-1), BA, D}
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick that specific file from the list. Read it line by line. Check each line if it is a comment. If Yes, Skip the line and continue. else split the line into words and store those words into an array of String. Put each element to its corresponding list. **Note:** The conditon `if (raw.length < 3)` is just used to handle the `enter` character as you have one at the end of line 4.

```
public class ReadContents {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList();

        ArrayList<String> tasks = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<String> hrs = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<String> others = new ArrayList();
        String[] raw;
        files.add(new File("File path"));
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files.get(0)))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("/*") | line.equals("")) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    raw = line.split("\\s+");
                    if (raw.length < 3) {
                        tasks.add(raw[0]);
                        hrs.add(raw[1]);
                        others.add("");
                    }else{
                        tasks.add(raw[0]);
                        hrs.add(raw[1]);
                        others.add(raw[2]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I avoid reading the comments and store each line in a proper order?

The simplest way to avoid comments is to use a simple method for denoting a comment. E.g. starting a line with `#` is often used to denote comments in simple scripting languages. Thus there is no need to parse for open/close comment contexts as inputs can be treated as whole lines.